# jquery event not registered to dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

This may be a duplicate question but i can't solve this problem.

navbar.php:

```
<li id="create_user"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i> <span>Create New User</span></a></li>
```

and in my main php file i enclude navbar.php as follow.

```
<html>
<?php $this->load->view("includes/headTag"); ?>
<body>
<!-- Main Container start -->
<!-- <div class="container main_container"> -->

    <?php $this->load->view("includes/dashboard_navbar.php"); ?>
    <?php $this->load->view("includes/sub_dashboard.php"); ?>
    <?php $this->load->view("includes/main_dashboard.php"); ?>

    <!-- load the contents from controller here -->
    <?php $this->load->view($path); ?>

    <?php $this->load->view("includes/footerScripts.php");?>

<!-- </div> -->
<!-- main container end -->
</body>
</html>
```

now using a test.js file i change the value of $path and load a new file.
The problem is jquery events are not registered to file contents and html elments added dynamically.

I know about

$("parent-selecter").on("event","child-selecter",callback(){});

but here i'm totally confused what to do.
Should i use something like

```
$("body").on("event","child-selecter",callback(){});
```

or?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Errr.. what's your question..? when does that new elements getting loaded and where does it getting loaded..? what are all those elements ..? Any way closing this question is a right course of action now..

Comment: you cannot change the value of $path using js. php works on server side and Js works on the client side, if I'am correct!

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy: This was not a duplicate of those questions. This was a simple error in calling the function rather than passing it.

Comment: @John: The code is a combination of *server-side* PHP and *client-side* JS, which is perfectly valid. They are not changing/using `$path` "client-side".

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: "now using a test.js file i change the value of $path and load a new file." I am asking about this line here! I'm confused here!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. $(element).on() is specifically made to work with dynamically added content, so as long as everything else is working right, on() should work too.

You can use on() to attach a click event on document like so:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event)
{
    //Do stuff
});
```

Child selector could be used like this for example:

```
$(table).on('click', 'td', function(event)
{
    //Do stuff
});
```

This attached a click even to each td element in a table to correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `"body"` with a delegated event handler. The safe fallback is to use `document` and the syntax is like this:

```
$(document).on("event","child-selecter",function(){ YOUR CODE HERE });
```

The problem with this is you are calling `callback` immediately and passing the result to the on function!:

```
$("body").on("event","child-selecter",callback(){});
```

should be

```
$(document).on("event","child-selecter",callback);
```

Notes: Delegated event handlers, using `on`, should attach to the first non-changing ancestor element for efficiency. `document` is the fallback if one is not conveniently available.

Answer (score 0):

`callback()` it executes immediately before on event. Use below code

```
$(document).on("event","child-selecter",callback);
```

Comment: Do not ever use `"body"` for delegated events. It does not handle `click` events correctly (depending on the styling). Use `document` as the fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Donot call the callback when registering an event listener:

Change this

```
$("body").on("event","child-selecter",callback(){});
```

to this

```
$(document).on("event","child-selecter",callback);
```